# How do I get screen video capture to record sound?

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, alsa

I have tried 5 different video screen recording application, and I have the same issue with all of them. When I play back the recorded video there is either no sound or an error message that the necessary codec is not installed and given the option to search for it, but the only thing that comes up are codecs I have already installed but apparently don't work.
Any assistance in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu
One error I received had to do with a missing Mp4-AAC Audio Codec

System:    Host: david-B360M-DS3H Kernel: 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu1) info: gnome-shell dm:

gdm3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Machine:   Device: desktop System: Gigabyte product: B360M-DS3H serial: N/A
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: B360M DS3H v: x.x serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: F3 date: 03/01/2018

CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i3-8100 (-MCP-) 
           arch: Skylake rev.11 cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 28800
           clock speeds: min/max: 800/3600 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 800 MHz
           3: 800 MHz 4: 800 MHz

Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 3e91 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:3e91
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes

Audio:     Card Intel Device a348
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a348
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-34-generic

Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000
           bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac:

Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (10.7% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD5000AVDS size: 500.1GB
           serial:  temp: 36C

Partition: ID-1: / size: 457G used: 49G (12%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 1.03GB used: 0.00GB (0%)
           fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1

RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A

Info:      Processes: 242 Uptime: 5:10 Memory: 1589.7/3809.7MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191 running in gnome-terminal-) inxi: 2.3.56

Comment: Providing full information (such as version of Ubuntu being used) allows us to be more precise, or the error message you talk of but don't provide.  As such we can provide only general advice - ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToCaptureDigitalVideo & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreencastTeam/RecordingScreencasts

Comment: Please install `inxi`, run `inxi -Fxxxz`, copy the output and post it here by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1070438/edit). Using [appropriate formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) will help make your post easy to read.

Comment: OK I added more information